# Keeping cookies when testing an addon

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox4

I'm developing an addon using Firefox Add-on SDK. I am using `cfx` to run my addons when testing.

The app posts some text when highlighted to twitter.

The problem is each time I modify the code I have to log back into twitter. Is there any way to ensure cookies are saved whilst testing/debugging? Similar to what happens when you open and close Firefox normally?

Comment: +1 for the question title alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are your parameters for calling `cfx`? By default, `cxf` executes in a **new profile.**

You need to use `-p PROFILEDIR` or `--profiledir=PROFILEDIR` param to use a specific profile, and associated settings.

From notes @ https://jetpack.mozillalabs.com/sdk/1.0b5/docs/dev-guide/addon-development/cfx-tool.html